# How to clear cache on click of bottom tabs in ionic 7 with vue 3

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps

I'm facing a caching issue. As per framework it is desired behaviour but I don't want to.

See that cache page I want to get is freshly.

Question: how to clear view cache on click of any bottom tabs? Real problem happens when we are there in page 2 and go to other tab then click it again it will show page 2 content.

Here is my problem:

[image]

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
   "@ionic/vue": "^7.0.0",
   "vue": "^3.2.45",
}
```

**TabsPage.vue**

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2" href="/tabs/tasks/project">
          <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" :icon="ellipse" />
          <ion-label>Taks</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="tab3" href="/tabs/tab1">
          <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" :icon="ellipse" />
          <ion-label>About</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

      </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import { IonTabBar, IonTabButton, IonTabs, IonLabel, IonIcon, IonPage, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/vue';
import { ellipse, square, triangle } from 'ionicons/icons';
</script>
```

Comment: its not cache, in tab 1, set an active tab index on page enter. once you enter page one, set the active index to 0 in order to make that active.. i'm not familiar with vue but till you haven't added the part related to the segements in your given so can't help more than that...

Comment: @MostafaHarb , not exactly actually ionic 7 is caching views for performance but i don't want view to be cached.

Comment: use ionic lifecycle events: https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/lifecycle
you can use `ionViewWillLeave()` method. in this function clear your variables and set your data to your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 7 with Vue 3, you can clear the cache on click of bottom tabs by using the router and utilizing the router.replace method. This method replaces the current route without adding it to the history stack, effectively clearing the cache.

Here's a simple example:

```
<template>
  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button @click="navigateToTab('/tab1')">
        <ion-icon :icon="homeOutline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button @click="navigateToTab('/tab2')">
        <ion-icon :icon="appsOutline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Tab 2</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</template>

<script>
import { IonTabs, IonRouterOutlet, IonTabBar, IonTabButton, IonIcon, IonLabel } from '@ionic/vue';
import { homeOutline, appsOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    IonTabs,
    IonRouterOutlet,
    IonTabBar,
    IonTabButton,
    IonIcon,
    IonLabel,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      homeOutline,
      appsOutline,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    navigateToTab(tabPath) {
      // Use router.replace to clear the cache when switching tabs
      this.$router.replace(tabPath);
    },
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Add your styles here */
</style>
```